# Getting position of the XML element inside For Each loop

Tags: vb.net, foreach, selectnodes

How do I get the position of the XML element in this loop?

```
For Each objNode In objDoc.SelectNodes("//books/book")

 ???

Next
```

What I want in output would be something like

1
2
3
4
....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
objBooks = objDoc.SelectSingleNode("//books")

Dim pos As Integer = 1
For Each book As XmlNode In objBooks.ChildNodes

   Console.Write(pos & " ")

   pos = pos + 1
Next
```